# Deriving $\operatorname{arccot}(x)=\int\limits_{x}^ {\infty} \frac{1}{1+t^2} ~dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

For $x\in \mathbb R$ we have $$\text{arccot}(x)=\int\limits_{x}^ {\infty} \frac{1}{1+t^2} ~dt.$$ How can we prove this? for if we have definite integral then for example after assuming some hypothesis we have
$$\text{arcsin}(x)=\text{arcsin}(0)+\int\limits_{0}^ {x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} ~dt.$$ By fundamental theorem of calculus. How we can use it for improper integral?
If $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that for all $x$, $\int\limits_{x}^ {\infty} f(t) ~dt$ converges. And if we define$~F$ on $(0,\infty)$ as
$$ x\mapsto \int\limits_{x}^ {\infty} f(t) ~dt$$
then I proved $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$.So if we have any other $G$ on  $(0,\infty)$ such that $G'(x)=f(x)$. Then by mean value theorem we have$$
G(x)=C+\int\limits_{x}^ {\infty} f(t) ~dt$$ for some constant $C$.
Is there any analogous for that constant $C$ like definite integral. Is $C=G(\infty)=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} G(x)$? Because here
$$\text{arccot}(x)=\lim\limits_{k\to \infty}\text{arccot}(k)+\int\limits_{x}^ {\infty} \frac{1}{1+t^2} ~dt.$$
So My question is about that constant $C$. Is there any way to get $C$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuously differentiable then
$$ \tag{1}
 F(y) - F(x) = \int_x^y F'(t) \, dt
$$
for all $x, y \in \Bbb R$ due to the fundamental theorem of calculus. (The conditions can be relaxed, e.g. that $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere and $F'$ is locally Lebesgue-integrable).

If, in addition, $C = \lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)$ exists then we can take the limit $y \to \infty$ in $(1)$ and conclude that
$$ \tag{2}
F(x) = C - \int_x^\infty F'(t)\, dt
$$

For $F(x) = \operatorname{arccot}(x)$ is $F'(x) = -\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and $C = \lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 0$, so that
$$
 \operatorname{arccot}(x) = \int_x^\infty \frac{1}{1+t^2} \, dt
$$

Comment: If $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} F(x)$ not exist . Then is there any way to find $C$ where $F(x) = C - \int_x^\infty F'(t)\, dt
$?

Comment: @MeetPatel: (1) shows that $\lim\limits_{y\to \infty} F(y)$  exists if and only if $\int_x^\infty F'(t)\, dt$ exists (for any $x$). Therefore, if the limit does not exist then $F(x) = C - \int_x^\infty F'(t)\, dt$ makes no sense.

Comment: I am confused with $F'$ and $F$ . Can we say that for continuous $f$ your statement is equivalent to 
$$ \int\limits_ {\infty}^{x} f(t) ~dt~~ \text{exist for all positive x}~  \text{iff ~ for ANY antiderivative G of f} ~\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} G(x) exist .$$
And $G(x)=~\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} G(t)+\int\limits_{\infty}^{x} f(t)$

Answer (score 6):

We have: $\cot^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+t^2}dt-\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x} \dfrac{1}{1+t^2}dt = \displaystyle \int_{x}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+t^2}dt$ which is the desire formula.

Comment: What if integrand is arbitrary ? Like I defined $F$ and $G$ .in that case how to get $C$?

Answer (score 1):

YES there is a way to find $C$. Hint $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{-}} \cot (x) =\infty$

Comment: It is in general true?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean we can always take limit at $\infty$ to get $C$.

Comment: Yes you can if the integral in defined